# AWS Lambda NodeJs response error when response data is large

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda

When I'm trying to return the response from a nodejs lambda function, I'm getting the following error:

```
Can't set headers after they are sent Error: Can't set headers after they are sent at validateHeader
```

If the response length is small, then I'm getting it in the response.

I tried sending hardcoded data and observed the same - getting the output for small data, but not for larger data.

The error is present in both the cases, but I'm getting the response if the data length is small.

How can we resolve it?

Adding part of the code for reviewing:

```
let videoInstance = await _searchVideo();

    if (!videoInstance) {
      const err = new APIError('Video not found!', HTTPStatus.NOT_FOUND, true);
      return next(err);
    }
    let collections = await parseVideoList([videoInstance]);
    if (req.accessToken && req.accessToken.obj) {
      collections = _.filter(collections, collection => {
        return collection.subscribed;
      });
    }
    let respObj = {
      _embedded: {
        collections
      }
    }

    res.json(respObj);
  } catch (exec) {
    return next(exec);
  }
```

Comment: This is so vague. Do you have any code we can review?

Comment: @J.Stott, I just edited the question. The error is present in both the cases, but I'm getting the response if the data is small.
 I have added the code for reviewing.

Comment: You should include more relevant code.

Comment: If you can move away from `express`, that would be a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround for for this issue. I did the following:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(respObj));
```

I can still see the error in the console, but I'm getting the response in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see an error message that says "can't set headers after they are sent", it means that somewhere you already sent an http response and tried to do that again. I guess the real problem here is in the logic, not in the fact that you have small or big data. Maybe some if statement is not properly configured.

Comment: I was trying to figure out the same, but it's occurring only when deployed in aws lambda. I'm using aws-serverless-express for this. 
If I run the code in the usual way, it's working without any error.

Comment: @PETER please, update your snippet in the question so that it contains the whole controller callback, middleware and http method mapping

Answer (score 0):

As @Vladyslav mentioned. The error occurs when you are trying to send a response to an already sent http response.

I would guess that you should do:

`return res.json(resObj)`

And see the error disappear.